# Spring Boot Post API returns null values

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I've been playing around with Spring MVC and came across an issue, where I send a JSON object from the frontend with JavaScript to the backend. To do so, I use a POST Method, which seems to return null values on the backend.

JavaScript:

```
function calcBudget() {
    var table = document.getElementById("mainTable");
    const jsonBody = [];

    for (var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
        const jsonItem = {};

        jsonItem ["name"] = table.rows[i].cells[0].firstChild.value;
        jsonItem ["category"] = table.rows[i].cells[1].firstChild.value;
        jsonItem ["amount"] = table.rows[i].cells[2].firstChild.value;

        jsonBody.push(jsonItem);
    }

    console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonBody));

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "/home/test", true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify({
        jsonBody
    }));
}
```

JavaScript Output:

```
[{"name":"01","category":"01","amount":"03"}]
```

RestController:

```
@Controller
public class GreetingsController {

    @PostMapping("/home/test")
    public String readInput(@RequestBody CalcModel model) {
        System.out.println(model.expenseName +" " + model.expenseCategory+" "+ model.expenseAmount);
        return "index";
    }
}
```

RestController Output:

```
null null null
```

CalcModel:

```
public class CalcModel {

public String expenseName;
public String expenseCategory;
public Double expenseAmount;

public CalcModel(String expenseName, String expenseCategory, Double expenseAmount) {
    this.expenseName = expenseName;
    this.expenseCategory = expenseCategory;
    this.expenseAmount = expenseAmount;
}
}
```

Why is the RestController output null? I have attempted to integrate an H2 database, as I assumed I would need one. Turned out, though, that this does not work either. I also tried to use getters for the CalcModel, without any luck. Any ideas?

Edit:
It seems as I'm sending a JSON array to Spring Boot, which expects to find just a single object, not an array of objects. Removing the square brackets seems to solve the issue when testing via Postman. Now I need to find a solution how to make SpringBoot recognize the response body as a JSON array.

**Solution:**
Change RestController Method to this (Request Body needs to be an ArrayList)

```
@PostMapping("/home/test")
public String readInput(@RequestBody ArrayList<CalcModel> model) {
    for (CalcModel calcModel : model) {
        System.out.println(calcModel.name + " " + calcModel.category + " " + calcModel.amount);
    }
    return "index";
}
```

In the JavaScript file, remove the curly brackets

```
xhr.send(JSON.stringify(jsonBody));
```

Comment: Generate getters and setters on the model class

Comment: I did, but that does not solve the issue unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have different namings in the jsonBody and the CalcModel. Try changing the names to the same thing.

```
[{"name":"01","category":"01","amount":"03"}]

public class CalcModel {

public String name;
public String category;
public Double amount;
```

You might also need a parameterless constructor and getters and setters.

Comment: I gave both of your suggestions a try, but it still seems not to work

Comment: I think I found the issue. My JSON I'm sending is an array, SpringBoot on the other hand expects to find a single Object. At least that's what I could find from testing it with Postman. No idea why it is not throwing the same error when attempting it directly via JavaScript